# How to pass character array in system() function in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I want to execute linux commands using c++ platform and I am using system() but when i write:

```
cout<<"Enter the command"<<endl;
cin>>arraystring[size];

system(arraystring.c_str());
```

it gives error!

```
a4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a4.cpp:75:20: error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘arraystring’, which is of non-class type ‘std::string [100] {aka std::basic_string<char> [100]}’
 system(arraystring.c_str());
```

What should i do to overcome this error?

Comment: How is `arraystring` defined?

Comment: char arraystring[100];

Comment: is there any other way to execute linux commands using c++ platform??

Comment: Not according to your error message, unless you've used a preprocessor macro to define `char` as `std::string`.

Comment: i had initially declared std::string but now i have edit it to char * but still a4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a4.cpp:75:20: error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘arraystring’, which is of non-class type ‘char [100]’
 system(arraystring.c_str());

Comment: You really want to learn about `fork`  & `execve` & `waitpid`  (the basic [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) that `system(3)`  is using). So read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) since it has several chapters about them; be afraid of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) issues

Comment: instead of system call i should use fork and execve??

Comment: `char*` is not a class it's a pointer to a basic data type in c++, consequently it has no member functions such as `c_str()`

Comment: You definitely can (and you probably should) use *syscalls* like [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) etc... (unless your teacher tells you to not use them). However, your misunderstanding is about basic C++ programming (not related to [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3html) which is *not* a syscall), and you should dive into a good [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) book. That may take weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have defined your `arraystring` variable as:

```
string arraystring[100];
```

Hence, when you write the statement

```
system(arraystring.c_str);
```

`arraystring` being an array of `std::string`, gives the error.

Change it to:

```
system(arraystring[size].c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
std::string command;
std::cout << "Enter the command" << endl;
std::cin >> command;

system(command.c_str());
```

That will work as long as `command` is just one word. If you want to use multi-word commands, you can use:

```
std::getline(std::cin, command);
system(command.c_str());
```

Comment: ok thanks it works but is there any other way to run linux commands on c++ platform as we are prohibited to use system call by our instructor.

Comment: and i cannnor upvote you need 15 reputations, can you give me a reputation??

Comment: @mahnoorfatima, it's ok. You can upvote when you can. There is no need to hurry.

Comment: if you have a book in standard c++ programming you wont get so much knowledge about linux system calls but while you are reading standard c++, you can have a look to manual pages of linux c and c++ system calls

Comment: in terminal it is very useful to use man page you can try `man fork`  and etc. In your linux terminal comand line you will get a very useful instruction on how to use these functions in your program